# Does IIS Express support ASP Classic?

Tags: asp-classic, iis-express

I forgot to install IIS in my last dev machine repave and was thinking that maybe the new IIS Express can fit the bill for running the old ASP Classic sites I'm supporting.

**Do you know if IIS Express supports ASP Classic?**

Comment: Why can't you install IIS now?

Comment: Because is more fun to do something new than working :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it supports.
[More infos.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/)